# How to tell ReSharper to act case sensitive on autosuggestion?

Tags: resharper, autosuggest

When I program in ReSharper and autosuggestion pops up and I type:

"item"

it Suggests:

- Item
- itemId

and selects the first Value. But I want reSharper to give the one with the correct writing (small "i"=>itemId) a higher priority like VS usually acts by default and select that when I press Enter or Tab

Comment: What types are 'Item' and 'itemId'? If they are both properties of a class then typing `<object>.I` will select 'Item' and typing `<object>.i` will select 'itemId' (this is with Resharper 5 and VS2008). Might be good to give more details / code snippet.

Comment: itemId is an field within the current function, Item is a class property. But I don't think it does matter. Resharper just selects the fully written value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that ReSharper tries to select the closest match between your input and available completion options. Actually in your particular case, it selects the lower-case option (itemId) on i, it, and ite - that is, until you type in the entire word "item". An apparent solution would be to press Enter or Tab as soon as you've hit the first character )